# Gradient descent derivation for orthogonal linear regression from scratch in Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

[image]

I wanted to derive gradient descent from scratch using the error function for Orthogonal linear regression. So that I could write python code in NumPy.
However, I am unsure about the error function in this.

y = W0 + W1 * X

Can anyone help me derive this!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `y = m*x + p` with `(m; p)` being the parameters you are tuning.

When you feed an observation sample X of X' through your model, you obtain a vector Y'. Then, you can compute your loss, say a mean square error, as `e = 1 / n * sum_i (Yi - Yi')²'` where `Y` is the y-coordinates associated to the x-coordinates in `X`.

Now, we want to differentiate e relative to your parameters:

- `de / dm = -2 / sigma² * sum_i ( Xi' * ( Yi - p - m * Xi' ) )`
- `de / dp = -2 / sigma² * sum_i ( Yi - p - m * Xi' )`

Then you want to minimize `e` thanks to this gradient:

- `m <- m - lr * de / dm`
- `p <- p - lr * de / dp`

With `lr` being your learning rate.

Do the math on your own though, just in case I made an error.

EDIT: I've implemented it quickly using those formulas and the math seems ok (at least it converges to the solution quickly)

Comment: Yes, I got the math part which you did which is the linear regression method however I wanted to derive the error function for orthogonal regression.

Comment: what is the value of sigma if I may know

Comment: I just derive the error function is

error = (1 / (1 + m^2)) * (y - mx - p) ^2

however think it is only limited to 2D, not with nth dimension I am working on it to generalize it.

Comment: Sigma is the standard deviation of the observation error.

Comment: I don't know how you've differentiated it. The model implemented in my answer should work in nD.

Comment: I am considering this link solution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803209/minimize-the-sum-of-distances-to-a-line

Comment: also, can you give the exact value of sigma if possible?

Comment: Well, this value depends on your problem. I am using the notations from here if you want a better understanding of it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression. The solution you linked is more complicated than this as a orthogonal regression is a simplification of the problem in the link.

Comment: Got it. I will go through it.

Comment: I couldn’t go on weekend without correcting a mistake I made: this only works in 1D. If you want to extend it to nD, you want to compute the Jacobian of `e` instead of its gradient. Then you would have to minimize 2*n equations to do your descent. If you are not familiar with doing it in 1D, I can’t recommend you to try and implement it in nD. Have a good weekend :)